# Features on a list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, feature, custom-actions, solution

How can I see the **features attached to a list**? (ex: which *feature create an item custom action*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to find this information

```
function Get-SPCustomAction 
{   
    trap [Exception] { continue; } 
    cls 
    $null = [system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.Sharepoint") 
    $null = [system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.Sharepoint.Administration") 
    $null = [system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Web") 
    [string]$xmlString = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?><CustomActions>" 
    $farm = [microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm]::local 
    foreach ($featureDef in $farm.FeatureDefinitions) 
    { 
        trap [Exception] { continue; } 
        foreach ($elementDef in $featureDef.GetElementDefinitions([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)) 
        { 
            trap [Exception] { continue; } 
            $node = $elementDef.XmlDefinition; 
            if ($node.Name -eq "CustomAction") 
            { 
                trap [Exception] { write-error $($_.Exception.Message); continue; } 
                $xmlString += "<CustomAction Id=""" + $node.Id + """ GroupId=""" + $node.GroupId + """ Location=""" + $node.Location + """ Sequence=""" + $node.Sequence + """ Title=""" + $node.Title + """ " 
                if($node.UrlAction -ne $null -and $node.UrlAction.OuterXml -ne "" -and $node.UrlAction.Url -ne $null -and $node.UrlAction.Url -ne "") 
                { 
                    $xmlString +=  "Url=""" + [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($node.UrlAction.Url.ToString()) + """ "
                } 
                $xmlString += " 
xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/""/>" 
            } 
        } 
    }  

    $xmlString += "</CustomActions>" 

    #$xmlString = $xmlString.Replace("&", " ") 
    Write-Output  $xmlString 
}
```

This will list down all custom action in a Farm. You can also print the `$featureDef.Name` to find the feature Name

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ekraus/archive/2010/05/03/list-all-customactions-in-the-farm.aspx